# Does somebody know a workaround for this problem with eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using lint staged and husky to verify the commits, however since today it shows me the following error in the precommit logs.

```
ESLint: 8.30.0

Error: .eslintrc.cjs:
    Configuration for rule "indent" is invalid:
    Value {"allowIndentationTabs":true} should be equal to one of the allowed values.
    Value {"allowIndentationTabs":true} should be integer.
    Value {"allowIndentationTabs":true} should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

This is my config in the .eslintrc.cjs file

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard'
  ],
  overrides: [
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react'
  ],
  rules: {
    indent: ['error', { allowIndentationTabs: true }]
  }
}
```

I have been trying different solutions but in the end they all give the same error

Comment: `trying different solutions` - what *solutions* have you tried? have you read any *documentation*?

Comment: I tried to modify the eslint configuration but it gives problems with prettier like this one 

 "indent": ["error", 4]

Answer (score 0):

[indent](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent) rule doesn't have that option

[no-tabs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-tabs) has it but I guess it's not what you wanted